# Using ReactType with JSX

Tags: typescript, reactjs

I have a question regarding JSX and Typescript integration. Given the following code:

```
interface Props {
    component?: React.ReactType
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<Props, void> {
    render() {
      var Comp = this.props.component
      return (<Comp></Comp>)
    }
}
```

I get: `JSX element type 'Comp' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

How do I fix this? Similar code works fine in Javascript where `component` has prop validator `elementType` from [react-prop-types](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-prop-types), so it could be either a string or component class.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the definition of react type in typing, you will find that you have a union type of 3 different types, one of which is a string. That's why you had such a problem. Try replacing React.ReactType with React.ComponentClass.

Comment: But I want a string too, it is allowed in react javascript.

Comment: @user3250645 then you shouldn't use typescript. There are a lot of correct programs which you can't type. It's a trade-off, you loose some freedom of expression but gain more safety.

Comment: the issue has nothing to do with typescript as a language. Obviously its type system is flexible enough to express what is needed (i.e. ReactType). The issue is that JSX parser in typescript expects JSX.Element class and I don't know that how bridge between ReactType (which may mean simple string) and JSX.Element (which expects React.Component). I'm sure it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

How are you creating the component that you're passing in?  If you create it like this it should work:

```js
interface MyProps {
    component?: React.ReactType;
}

class TestComponent extends React.Component<void, void> {
    render() {
        return <div>Test</div>;
    }
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyProps, void> {
    render() {
        const Comp = this.props.component
        return (<Comp/>);
    }
}


class Parent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    render() {
       return (
          <MyComponent component={TestComponent}></MyComponent>
       )
    }
}
```

You could also pass an html element as a string (e.g. "div"), but I'm not sure if that's what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example using the functional component:

```
type YourProps = { count: number };
type Props = {
  component: ElementType<YourProps>
}

function Parent({component}: Props): ReactElement {

  return (
    <>
      {React.createElement(component, {count: 1})}
    </>
  );
}

function Child({count}: YourProps) {
  return <>Count: {count}</>
}

function Root() {
  return <><Parent component={Child}/></>
}
```

In this case you will delegate the construction of element for the Parent component and it would natively create by using React API - createElement and passing props into it.